# tensorflow 2.3 : How to get output from a specific layer after combining custom models

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network

Say I have following 2 custom models structure

```
class Model_1(Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Model_1,self).__init__()
        
    def call(self,inputs):
        #x = inputs
        x = Dense(3,name="model_1_dense_1")(inputs)
        x = Dense(2,name="model_1_dense_2")(x)
        
        #out = x
        return x
    
class Model_2(Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Model_2,self).__init__()
        
    def call(self,inputs):
        #x = inputs
        x = Dense(5,name="model_2_dense_1")(inputs)
        x = Dense(4,name="model_2_dense_2")(x)
        
        #out = x
        return x
```

Now create objects of above as below, and then create Models using them while specifying the input layers

```
model1_obj = Model_1()
model2_obj = Model_2()

inp1 = Input(shape=(10,))
m1 = Model(inp,model1_obj.call(inp1))

inp2 = Input(shape=(2,))
m2 = Model(inp2,model2_obj.call(inp2))
```

I wish to combine these 2 models together, so I do the following

```
combined = Model(m1.inputs,m2.call(m1.outputs))
```

Model summary of combined model looks good as

```
combined.summary()

Model: "functional_7"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         [(None, 10)]              0         
_________________________________________________________________
model_1_dense_1 (Dense)      (None, 3)                 33        
_________________________________________________________________
model_1_dense_2 (Dense)      (None, 2)                 8         
_________________________________________________________________
model_2_dense_1 (Dense)      (None, 5)                 15        
_________________________________________________________________
model_2_dense_2 (Dense)      (None, 4)                 24        
=================================================================
Total params: 80
Trainable params: 80
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

All is good, and I can do the training etc.

Now lets say I would like to get the output from `model_2_dense_1` after training.
So I build another Model as below, but I am getting a `Graph disconnected error`

```
trimed_model = Model(combined.inputs,combined.get_layer("model_2_dense_1").output)
# ERROR #
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-71bcca7e8f84> in <module>
----> 1 trimed_model = Model(combined.inputs,combined.get_layer("model_2_dense_1").output)
--snip--
ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor("input_2:0", shape=(None, 2), dtype=float32) at layer "model_2_dense_1". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []
```

If I try to get output from "model_1_dense_2", the model gets created. However, non of the model_2 layers.

Note:
the reason by I am using `call` functionality is, so that in the `combined_model` I have proper information about all the layers inside, and I dont end up with `functional block` being shown up in summary and also so that I can refer to any layer in the network to get an output.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue. Basically, when building the `m2` I should not have created it as `m2 = Model(inp2,model2_obj.call(inp2))` This is where the problem is.

See below for full solution

```
# class objects #
model1_obj = Model_1()
model2_obj = Model_2()

# TF models (only for model1_obj) #
inp = Input(shape=(10,))
m1 = Model(inp,model1_obj.call(inp))

# Now build output for model2 #
m2_output = model2_obj.call(m1.output)

# Now build the combined model #
combined = Model(inp,m2_output)
```

Now there are only 1 input layer, and there is no chance of graph disconnections.
Earlier, I was disconnecting the `m2 model`, by providing it a different INPUT layer all together.

```
# A summary of combined model #
combined.summary()

Model: "functional_3"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         [(None, 10)]              0         
_________________________________________________________________
model_1_dense_1 (Dense)      (None, 3)                 33        
_________________________________________________________________
model_1_dense_2 (Dense)      (None, 2)                 8         
_________________________________________________________________
model_2_dense_1 (Dense)      (None, 5)                 15        
_________________________________________________________________
model_2_dense_2 (Dense)      (None, 4)                 24        
=================================================================
Total params: 80
Trainable params: 80
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Now we can select any layer that we want from this structure, and get the output

```
trimed_model = Model(combined.inputs,combined.get_layer("model_2_dense_1").output)
trimed_model.summary()
Model: "functional_5"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         [(None, 10)]              0         
_________________________________________________________________
model_1_dense_1 (Dense)      (None, 3)                 33        
_________________________________________________________________
model_1_dense_2 (Dense)      (None, 2)                 8         
_________________________________________________________________
model_2_dense_1 (Dense)      (None, 5)                 15        
=================================================================
Total params: 56
Trainable params: 56
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Another instances with a different layer (belonging to model1)

```
trimed_model = Model(combined.inputs,combined.get_layer("model_1_dense_2").output)
trimed_model.summary()
Model: "functional_7"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         [(None, 10)]              0         
_________________________________________________________________
model_1_dense_1 (Dense)      (None, 3)                 33        
_________________________________________________________________
model_1_dense_2 (Dense)      (None, 2)                 8         
=================================================================
Total params: 41
Trainable params: 41
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

:-)